How to fetch multiple document ids in Firebase Realtime Database?
my goal is to fetch multiple documents in one fetch.
The problem is, I don't know how to do it except to fetch it one by one.
What I've tried:

call the fetchByDocumentIdHelper in a loop, each request cost 600ms. This is not scalable.
try to use onValue. However, I don't know how to just fetch specific documentIds.

This function is to fetch 1 document.
async function fetchByDocumentIdHelper(
  database: Database,
  documentId: string
): Promise<AgencyRealtimeModel> {
  const dbRef = ref(database);
  const query = child(dbRef, `agencies/${documentId}`);
  const dataSnapshot = await get(query);

  if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
    return {};
  }

  const id = documentId;
  const data = dataSnapshot.val();

  const model: AgencyRealtimeModel = {
    id: id,
    data: data,
  };

  return model;
}

This function is to fetch multiple documents
async function fetchByDocumentIdsHelper(
  database: Database,
  documentIds: string[]
): Promise<AgencyRealtimeModel[]> {
  const models: AgencyRealtimeModel[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < documentIds.length; i++) {
    const documentId = documentIds[i];
    const model = await fetchByDocumentIdHelper(database, documentId);
    models.push(model);
  }

  return models;
}


await doesn't work in a for : loop. Use for of or Promise.all instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

@FrankvanPuffelen Hi, so is my assumption correct that Realtime Database don't support getting multiple documents in one fetch?

That's correct, nor does it need to as the requests are pipelined on the wire already and the server behaves single-threaded anyway. See my explanation here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

For now, I will use Promise.all
async function fetchByDocumentIdsHelper(
  database: Database,
  documentIds: string[]
): Promise<AgencyRealtimeModel[]> {
  const models: AgencyRealtimeModel[] = await Promise.all(
    documentIds.map(async (documentId) => {
      const dbRef = ref(database);
      const query = child(dbRef, `agencies/${documentId}`);
      const dataSnapshot = await get(query);

      const id = documentId;
      const data = dataSnapshot.val();

      const model: AgencyRealtimeModel = {
        id: id,
        data: data,
      };

      return model;
    })
  );

  return models;
}

